# Trigo equation $3\cos^2(2x)=1+\sin x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How to solve $3\cos^2(2x)=1+\sin (x)$? $0\leq x \leq 360$

I've been figuring this question for a such time. My lecturer told me this was a wrong question, I didn't know why.

Comment: Note that $\cos^2(2x)=(1-2\sin^2 x)^2$. You get a fourth degree equation.

Comment: And it will expand become $12x^4-12x^2-x+2 =0 $ where $x = sin(x)

Comment: That horrible quartic equation has, according to WA, four horrible real roots. It is highly unlikely one will ever meet such a beast in any trigonometry exam.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\cos 2x = 1 - 2\sin^2 x \\
3\cos^2 2x = 3(1 - 2\sin^2 x)^2 = 3 (1 - 4\sin^2 x + 4\sin^4 x)= 1 + \sin x. 
$$

$$
t = \sin x
$$

$$
3 - 12t^2 + 12t^4 = 1 + t
$$
Which has four real solutions for $t$.

Answer (score 1):

As DonAntonio commented, using the analytical method for the solution of $$12x^4-12x^2-x+2 =0$$ would lead to some nightmares and I suggest that you solve the problem using, say, Newton method for each of the roots.

If you plot the function for $-1\leq x \leq 1$, you will notice that the roots are close to $-0.8$, $-0.5$, $0.4$ and $0.9$.

Starting from a guess $x_0$, Newton method will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ which, for your case, gives  $$x_{n+1}=\frac{36 x_n^4-12 x_n^2-2}{48 x_n^3-24 x_n-1}$$ Applying the method with each of the approximate root we have
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
0 &  -0.800000 \\
 1 & -0.794479 \\
 2 & -0.794307 
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
0 & -0.500000 \\
 1 & -0.550000 \\
 2 & -0.554289 \\
 3 & -0.554333 
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.400000 \\
 1 & 0.398300 \\
 2 & 0.398299 
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.900000 \\
 1 & 0.960265 \\
 2 & 0.950629 \\
 3 & 0.950341 
\end{array}
\right)$$

All of this can be done using your calculator.